# find in range of a IDL array?

Tags: matlab, idl-programming-language

I am trying to find all indices in an array A, where the value larger than time0 and less than time1. In matlab I can do:

```
[M,F] = mode(  A((A>=time0) & (A<=time1))  ) %//only interested in range
```

I have something similar in IDL but really slow:

```
tmpindex0 = where(A ge time0)   
tmpindex1 = where(A lt time1)   
M = setintersection(tmpindex0,tmpindex1)
```

where setintersection() is function find the intersected elements between two arrays. What is the fast alternative implementation?

Answer (score 1):

You can combine your conditions:

```
M = where(A ge time0 and A lt time1, count)
```

Then `M` will contain indices into `time0` and `time1` while `count` will contain the number of indices. Generally, you want to check `count` before using `M`.

Answer (score 0):

This works (slight modification from mgalloy answer):

```
M = where( (A ge time0) and (A lt time1), n_match, complement=F, n_complement=ncomp)
```

The parenthetical separation is not necessary but adds clarity. `n_match` contains the number of matches to your conditions whereas the complement `F` will contain the indices for the non-matches and `ncomp` will contain the number of non-matches.